# Estimating a probability

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

I am interested in the probability of a random deal in bridge to be a par-
 zero-deal (a deal where no player can make any contract assuming perfect play
 with all hands visible)

The events I need for this are :

$$A : No\ player\ has\ at\ least\ 7\ tricks\ in\ no-trump$$

$$B : No\ player\ has\ at\ least\ 7\ tricks\ in\ spades$$

$$C : No\ player\ has\ at\ least\ 7\ tricks\ in\ hearts$$

$$D : No\ player\ has\ at\ least\ 7\ tricks\ in\ diamonds$$

$$E : No\ player\ has\ at\ least \ 7\ tricks\ in\ clubs$$

The probability of a par-zero-deal is then $$P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D \cap E)$$

> First question : Is it correct, that the probabilities for the events B,C,D,E
>    are the same due to symmetry ? (If a player has at least $7$ tricks in spades,
>    but no player in hearts, for example, exchanging the spades cards with the
>    hearts cards will result in a deal, where a player has at least $7$ tricks in 
>    hearts, but no player in spades)

A sample of $$2^{21}\times 5=10\ 485\ 760$$ deals reveals the following counts 
 (see deal-finder from brigge expert Richard Pavlicek, new version)

$A : 1\ 326\ 738$

$B : 459\ 124$

$C : 458\ 852$

$D : 458\ 976$

$E : 458\ 591$

$B\cap C : 27\ 413$

$B\cap D : 27\ 496$

$B\cap E : 27\ 155$

$C\cap D : 27\ 608$

$C\cap E : 27\ 117$

$D\cap E : 27\ 390$

$B\cap C\cap D : 1\ 883$

$B\cap C \cap E : 1\ 826$

$B\cap D \cap E : 1\ 906$

$C\cap D \cap E : 1\ 881$

> Second question : Is the symmetric argument also valid for the intersection
>     of two or three of the events B,C,D,E or are the probabilities different ?

$A\cap B : 60\ 984$

$A\cap C : 60\ 655$

$A\cap D : 60\ 663$

$A\cap E : 60\ 646$

> Third question : What is the best possible estimate for $P(B)$ with the given
>     data, same for $P(B\cap C)$ and so on.

Finally

$B\cap C \cap D\cap E : 129$

$A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap E : 25$

So, a rough estimate for the desired probability is $1 : 419\ 430$

> Fourth question : What is the best estimate for the desired
>     probability $P(A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap E)$ ?
>
> Fifth and last question : Can the desired probability be derived from
>     mathematical analysis, or is such an approach too complicated ?

Comment: Given that there are $13$ possible tricks, one of the two pairs must win at least $7$ of them.  So I doubt there are any cases as in your question: if there are then it must depend on the advantage of initial  lead in all five cases of trumps (your symmetry argument does not work with *no trumps*).  Unless you can actually demonstrate a case, I would put the combined probability as $0$.

Comment: What is meant that no matter, which player declares a contract, the opposite side (which begins the game) can make at least 7 tricks. Note that the player after the declarer in the cyclic order E-S-W-N is the one leading (beginning the game).

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge for further informations.

Comment: Richard Pavlicek's site is also very valuable : http://www.rpbridge.net/